# php regex via using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a variable `$play` which is made up of characters and numbers. For example:

`$play = "blah05"`

how do i use `preg_match()` to only get 05?
is my `$regexp` correct?

```
$regexp = "/^[^0-9]/";
if (preg_match($regexp, $play, $matches)) {
   echo "matches[0]";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get numbers from the end, regexp should be this:

`$regexp = '/(\d+)$/';`

if you want to get numbers from anywhere in the string:

`$regexp = '/(\d+)/';`

and just do `var_dump($matches);` to see the results and choose which option is best for you.

```
if (preg_match($regexp, $play, $matches)) {
   var_dump($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$regexp = "/([0-9]+)$/";
if (preg_match($regexp, $play, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

This captures the ones which have the number at the end of the string remove the $ if you want to capture the ones which have the number anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regexp = "/[0-9]+/";
if (preg_match($regexp, $play, $matches)) {
   echo $matches[0];
}
```

[0-9] are the numbers. And with + you match at least one number (as much as possible).